# Trouble with mod_proxy and mongrel_rails

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, mod-proxy, mongrel

I'm trying to set up a mod_proxy - mongrel combination, but somehow, apache/mod_proxy is unable to access mongrel locally. The following is my configuration for mod_proxy:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Location>
```

Mongrel/Rails ist running just fine, because I can access it from my browser, and even with lynx on the server.

However, I get the following error when trying to use the proxy:

```
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] Invalid Content-Length
```

I would appreciate any help :D

PS: Oh, and the server is running Plesk to configure vhosts, if thats important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of solved the problem by starting the mongrel server with

```
mongrel_rails start -d
```

instead of

```
ruby script/server -d
```

Not sure what the actual problem was, just happy that its working now :)